# Register action with Autofac per application start

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, autofac

I'm using MVC with Autofac. I'd like to register action that runs once per application start. I'd like to achieve sth. like this:

```
public class SomeModule : IOnceRunnable
{
   private IService service;

   public SomeModule(IService service) 
   {
       this.service = service;
   }

   public void Action()
   {
      // this action would be called once on application start
   }
}

containerBuilder.RegisterOnceRunnable<SomeModule>();
```

It is possible to perform such an action?

I know I could use built container (`var container = builder.Build();` <-- resolve manually services) but maybe there is more "elegant" solution like that above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is the [Startable Components](https://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/Startable) support in Autofac.

You need to implement the `Autofac.IStartable` interface:

```
public class SomeModule : Autofac.IStartable
{
   private IService service;

   public SomeModule(IService service) 
   {
       this.service = service;
   }

   public void Start()
   {
      // this action would be called once on application start
   }
}
```

you also need to register your type as `IStartable`:

```
builder
   .RegisterType<SomeModule>()
   .As<IStartable>()
   .SingleInstance();
```

and Autofac will do the rest the run the `Start` method once when the container is built.